# Dimension of the space of harmonic one-forms on compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, hodge-theory

It is shown by Hodge theory that the space of k-harmonic forms are isomorphic to the space of k-cohomology class, and for harmonic one-forms on compact manifold we also know that they must be parallel ($\nabla X = 0$, where $X$ is its dual vector field). But if two harmonic one-forms coincide at a point p ($X_p = Y_p$), then at any other point q, let $c(t)$ be a path joining p to q (we also assume the manifold is connected here), we then have $\nabla_\dot{c} X = \nabla_\dot{c} Y = 0$, but since $X$ and $Y$ coincide at p, by unique parallel transport, they must also coincide at q. Since q is arbitrary, $X$ must coincide with $Y$ everywhere, but this shows that the dimension of the space of harmonic one-forms is less than or equal to the dimension of the manifold, which yields a contradiction when one considers a compact surface with many genuses, whose first cohomology classes could have dimension much greater than 2. I wonder what is the problem in my reasoning?

Comment: Parallel transport will still depend on the homotopy class of a closed curve. Recall that flat bundles come from representations of $\pi_1$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see why homotopy class of the parallel transport yields any problem, could you please explained it a bit more detailedly?

Comment: How are you going to prove parallel transport is path-independent?

Comment: I choose a specific path $c(t)$ and parallel transport along this path, and it turns out that because $X$ and $Y$ coincide at $c(0)$, they must also coincide at $c(1)$, since $\nabla_\dot{c} X = \nabla_\dot{c} Y = 0$, the parallel transport could be different if I choose another path, but what I want to show is that $X$ and $Y$ would always coincide at the end point

Comment: That's not the point. Unless the manifold is simply connected, you do not have a globally well-defined harmonic $1$-form (or vector field) when you're done.

Comment: I have assumed that $X$ and $Y$ are globally well-defined harmonic 1-form, and then say that if they coincide at a specific point, they should coincide everywhere else

Comment: Ah, your translation into vector fields is a bit too glib. It is certainly the case that every parallel $1$-form is harmonic, but not every harmonic $1$-form is parallel.

Comment: I think we could show that harmonic 1-forms are parallel using the following formula: $ \triangle ||X||^2=2(<X , \triangle X>+||\nabla X||^2)=2||\nabla X||^2$, and then integrate over the manifold gives us $\int_M 2||\nabla X||^2=\int_M \triangle ||X||^2=0$, which implies $\nabla X=0$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see the problem, the above formula is not true, there should be a term involving the Ricci tensor. Thanks for your correction.